# Construct a XML from a list of strings representing nested properties

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm

I am trying to construct an XML, representing objects, but with ONLY the properties which have been modified between 2 objects, and the values in the second object. I don't know the structure of the classes, but I know that I will always have 2 objects of the same class.

Example :

```
public class A
{
    public B Property_A_B { get; set; }
    public C Property_A_C { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Property_B_Int { get; set; }
    public string Property_B_String { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public bool Property_C_Bool { get; set; }
    public D Property_C_D { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public double Property_D_Double { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 objects of type A. If the properties `Property_B_Int`, `Property_B_String` and `Property_D_Double` are not the same between my 2 objects, I have a string list which contains :

```
"A.Property_A_B.Property_B_Int"
"A.Property_A_B.Property_B_String"
"A.Property_A_C.Property_C_D.Property_D_Double"
```

Using these 3 strings, I have to construct that XML :

```
<A>
    <Property_A_B>
        <Property_B_Int>12345</Property_B_Int>
        <Property_B_String>Hello world</Property_B_String>
    </Property_A_B>
    <Property_A_C>
        <Property_C_D>
            <Property_D_Double>456.76</Property_D_Double>
        </Property_C_D>
    </Property_A_C>
</A>
```

The objects can have many different structures and dephts. I only know their types and the names of the properties which are different That function must work for any object.

I wrote that code :

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms)) {
        // Début du fichier
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        // Début de l'objet
        writer.WriteStartElement(Objet_Fin.GetType().Name);
        // Ecriture des champs modifiés
        foreach (Difference diff in Differences) {
            string[] composants_diff = diff.PropertyName.Split({ "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            object sous_objet = Objet_Fin;
            Type type_sous_objet = null;
            PropertyInfo sous_propriete = default(PropertyInfo);
            foreach (string composant_diff in composants_diff) {
                // Pour chaque itération, on navigue vers la propriété suivante
                type_sous_objet = sous_objet.GetType();
                sous_propriete = type_sous_objet.GetProperty(composant_diff);
                sous_objet = sous_propriete.GetValue(sous_objet);
                // On ouvre un noeud XML pour chaque propriété passée
                writer.WriteStartElement(composant_diff);
            }
            writer.WriteValue(sous_objet.ToString());
            foreach (string composant_diff in composants_diff) {
                // On ferme chaque noeud ouvert
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        // Fin de l'objet
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        // Fin du fichier
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        // Ecriture dans le flux
        writer.Flush();
    }
    // Ecriture du contenu du flux dans le XmlDocument
    ms.Position = 0;
    xml.Load(ms);
}
```

It almost works, but it generates the same object properties multiple times, instead of one. Something like that :

```
<A>
    <Property_A_B>
        <Property_B_Int>12345</Property_B_Int>
    </Property_A_B>
    <Property_A_B>
        <Property_B_String>Hello world</Property_B_String>
    </Property_A_B>
    <Property_A_C>
        <Property_C_D>
            <Property_D_Double>456.76</Property_D_Double>
        </Property_C_D>
    </Property_A_C>
</A>
```

I don't know how to generate correctly the XML with every object properties written only once. Please could you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: I would do a GroupBy and maybe a Distict method.

Comment: On what collection ? Oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one more day of work, I finally found it :

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement rootNode = xml.CreateElement(Objet_Fin.GetType().Name);
xml.AppendChild(rootNode);

// Pour chaque différence
foreach (Difference diff in Differences) {
    string[] composants_diff = diff.PropertyName.Split({ "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    XmlElement parentNode = rootNode;
    XmlElement currentNode = null;
    string currentXPath = "/" + rootNode.Name;
    // Pour chaque propriété imbriquée
    for (i = 0; i <= composants_diff.Length - 2; i++) {
        // Construction du Xpath 
        currentXPath += "/" + composants_diff(i);
        // Selection du node à tester
        currentNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode(currentXPath);
        if (currentNode == null) {
            // Si le node n'existe pas, on le créé et l'ajoute au parent
            currentNode = xml.CreateElement(composants_diff(i));
            parentNode.AppendChild(currentNode);
        }
        parentNode = currentNode;
    }
    // On écrit la propriété "finale"
    XmlNode newNode = xml.CreateElement(composants_diff.Last());
    newNode.InnerText = diff.Object2Value;
    parentNode.AppendChild(newNode);
}

return xml;
```

Hope someone will read that one day...

Answer (score 1):

The only correct way of doing this is using recursion.  I used StringReader() for testing and it can easily be modified to StreamReader().  I added some real tough test data to validate the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input1 = "a";
            List<XElement> results1 = ProcessData(input1);

            string input2 =
                "A.Property_A_B.Property_B_Int\n" +
                "A.Property_A_B.Property_B_String\n" +
                "A.Property_A_C.Property_C_D.Property_D_Double";

            List<XElement> results2 = ProcessData(input2);

            string input3 =
                "a.a.a.a.a.a.a\n" +
                "a.a.a.a.a.a.b\n" +
                "a.a.a.b";

            List<XElement> results3 = ProcessData(input3);

        }
        static List<XElement> ProcessData(string input)
        {

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string inputLine = "";
            List<List<string>> properties = new List<List<string>>();

            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                properties.Add(inputLine.Split(new char[] { '.' }).ToList());
            }
            List<XElement> results = Recursive(properties);

            return results;
        }

        static List<XElement> Recursive(List<List<string>> input)
        {
            List<XElement> results = new List<XElement>();
            string parent = input[0][0];

            Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dict = input.GroupBy(m => m.FirstOrDefault(), n => n)
                .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, n => n.Select(p => p.Skip(1).ToList<string>()).ToList());
            foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
            {
                List<List<string>> subChilds = dict[key];
                //List<XElement> subElements = new List<XElement>();
                for (int i = subChilds.Count() - 1; i >= 0;  i--)
                {
                    if (subChilds[i].Count() == 0)
                    {
                        subChilds.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
                List<XElement> child = null;
                if (subChilds.Count() > 0)
                {
                    child = Recursive(subChilds);
                    //elements.Add(child);

                }
                results.Add(new XElement(key, child));
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I don't understand... That looks much complex. I did not want to use recursion, because of the performance issues when we use recursion. This function may be called many times per second. The solution I found does not use recursion and is working, so I am going to use it.

Comment: Recursion doesn't change performance.  Try my 3rd test case and see if your code really works.

Comment: Recursion make the call stack grow, and more the recursion is "deep", more it grows. So it can bring memory issues. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes recursion adds to the stack, but it depends on the algorithm the degree of the memory used.  You probably only will have 10 layers of nesting which isn't terrible (one for each period in the source string).  You have a very small algorithm so i wouldn't worry.  I'm not using a lot of variables in the code so variable memory space isn't an issue either.  Recursion doesn't really effect speed and can be quicker than other methods.